# Управление элементами label в NavBar

Tags: php, yii2

Делаю на yii2 учебный блог!

У меня есть вкладка "My Blog":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Она отображается постоянно даже, когда никто не  залогинился - это не правильно!

**Как сделать так чтоб эта вкладка** `NavBar`а` **отображалась только в том случае если на странице залогиненный пользователь ?**

Comment: Посмотрите как сделано отображение Login и Logout и сделайте по аналогии

Comment: `if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest == false) { echo "My blog"; }` вот как-то так

Answer (score 2):

Если вы делаете через виджет, то добавьте рядом с label и url еще один индекс, для этого пункта:

```
'visible'=>!Yii::$app->user->isGuest,
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-nav.html